# jquery ajaxSubmit replaceTarget javascript

Tags: jquery

I have a div in this pattern:

```
<div id="register_container">


 ...
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
    alert('hi');
    $("#customer").css("backgroundColor", "red");
    $('#add_item_form').ajaxSubmit({target: "#register_container", replaceTarget: true});
 </script>
</div>
```

The first run around I get a background color of red on the #customer select box and an alert. The 2nd...n times around I get an alert but the #customer background doesn't change. It seems to be operating on the "Old" stuff. How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh i think maybe you are talking about re-submitting the form the color doesn't change? If that is the case you may need to add the code that changes the css background color to red to the ajaxSubmit event handler.

Answer (score 0):

try

$("#customer").css("background-color", "red");

Comment: IT has something to do with replaceTarget, but I am not sure why